# Left Shift and CTRL keys not working when Fn Keys are disabled in BIOS - Lenovo T440p

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo

I have a Lenovo T440p laptop. I would like to be able to use `ALT-F4` to close the active window in Ubuntu Desktop, but when I toggle the `Fn` Keys' behavior in the BIOS, the left `Shift` and `CTRL` keys stop working until I toggle it back...

Any ideas?